# Node version issue with npm

Tags: angular, npm, server, npm-install, npm-start

I am trying to start my `Angular` project server using `npm` but it won't start and giving a message as `Node.js version v12.20.1 detected.` I crossed checked the node version it is `16.20.1` Below is the message and the node version screenshot. I am using angular `14.2.12`

Please guide me how to get rid of this issue? (I dont want to use ng serve)

[image]

Comment: If you are on windows, how about check path to node in "environment variables"

Make sure user variables don't override system variables